# git status doesn't show new folder

Tags: git, version-control

After I add new folder in my project I can't see them as `untracked` files, for example if I add `js` folder I can't see with `git status` command.(I also tried `git status -u`)

(**Note:** I can see `js` folder in `git clean -nd`)

How I can realize a new folder added to my project in git ?

The second question but related is:

when I add `index.js` in `js` folder I get this following message:

```
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        js/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

why I can't see `index.js` as untracked files instead of `js` folder ? 
or something like `js/index.js`
or better question is how I can see what's new in `js` folder ?

I tried to find out the answer in ***stackoverflow questions*** and ***git document*** but I couldn't.

Comment: [git](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#_name) tracks **content**, not files/folders. This is by design. For the second part of your question, I'm not quite sure enough, I'll let others answer.

Comment: @paolo yeah but I couldn't check yesterday, now I can. thank you :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned, by default `git status` won't show files in a directory that is not tracked.

To explicitly request that, you can use:

```
git status --untracked-files
```

which will show:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        js/index.js
```

See the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#Documentation/git-status.txt---untracked-filesltmodegt).

Answer (score 1):

Git cannot track empty directories and hence you won't see your `js` directory. It will not look inside directories that are untracked so if you have files in there, they won't show up individually in `git status`. Only the directory will be visible.

Often, people add a `.track` inside empty directories so that empty directories will be tracked.

Comment: what's your mean by add `.track` and please tell me how I can do that ?

Comment: `touch empty_folder/.track` and then `git add empty_folder/.track` and `git commit`.

Comment: why I should commit that ?

Comment: So that the directory starts to get tracked.

Answer (score 1):

for the 2nd question
you can do `git add js/`
it will add index.js file as well

after above step you can try `git status`

then you will get:

```
Changes to be committed:

  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)

        **modified:   js/index.js**
```

---

For 1st question, `git status` should show untracked folder with path. strange if it's not coming for you.

```
Untracked files:

  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        js/
```